# unable to configure tomcat 8.5.57 webserver for https on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: tomcat8, tomcat9

I have installed tomcat on ubuntu 18.4. post default installation and jave home configurations able to see webserver page as response for http://:8080.

Later generated keystore and updated the details in conf/server.xml to enable https. Even after this am not getting tomcat default page with https, though getting web page over http / 8080 port.

Any pointer to debug / enable https on tomcat.?
Is Apache tomcat version 8.5 compatible with Ubuntu 18.04 version.?

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the server.xml, connector node for https was made with smaller case. was not aware of it as case sensitive. after making appropriate changes able to access https also.